# Python (tkinter) error : "CRC check failed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I'm doing a small GUI in python, and I wanna add a button with an image. So I'm following what's said here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-image-on-a-tkinter-button/

It gives :

```py
downimage = PhotoImage(file = "Downloadimage.png")
Dowloadbutton = Button(window, image=downimage, font=("Source Code Pro Light", 20), bg='black', fg='lime', command=start)
Dowloadbutton.pack()
```

As it is said in the link. But then the magic happens :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Keylogger.pyw", line 28, in <module>
    downimage = PhotoImage(file = "Downloadimage.png")
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: CRC check failed
```

Line 28 corresponds to `downimage = PhotoImage(file = "Downloadimage.png")`.
Everything else is packed and appear, but my button doesn't and gives me that error.
I don't know what it means, when I try to search it on internet, a lot of non-tkinter-related results appear, it seems to be not a common but still known error.

(I'm using the last version of both python and tkinter)

If you can help me, thank you really much ! Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In png format,`CRC` code is here.

(An example png image)
[image]

It was encrypted(CRC32) by image chunk[0].It is a little hard for me to express that.

But the cause of your problem is the width and height of image is incorrect(mostly).Your image size has been revised.

---

In fact,if you put your image in `linux`,the image couldn't be opened normally.In windows default image viewer,system will ignore `CRC` checksum error,and you could open it.

How to solve your problem?

1. Revise this image bytes.
2. Use a new,correct image.

Comment: Oookaaay thank you ! So my image is too big ? Or too small ? I think it's too big... Gonna check this !

Comment: I don't know if you didn't upload your image.Repairing your image seems a harder way,I suggest you use a new image.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this. Btw thank you for your explication, it was one of the clearest I've ever received here !